# Object reference not set to an instance of an object DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftContent" runat="Server">

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function setHash(obj) {
             var deger = $(obj).attr('links');

             $(".active").removeClass("active");
             $('.pagemenudu > li[id="' + deger + '"]').addClass("active");
             $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
             $(".iletisimdiv div#" + deger).addClass("highlight");
         }

         $(document).ready(function () {


         });

    </script>
    <ul class="pagemenuDepo">

        <li id="conform" class="active"><a onclick='setHash(this);' links="conform"><%= GetLocalResourceObject("header").ToString().ToUpper() %><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content15" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightContent" runat="server">


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formcontrol(objs) {
            var form = $("form:first");
            $('#' + $(form).attr("id")).validate({
                ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
                rules: {

                    '<%= dtTarih.UniqueID %>': {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    '<%= ddlDepoId.UniqueID %>': {
                        required: {
                            depends: function (element) {
                                return $("#MainContent_RightContent_ddlDepoId").val() == '';
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    '<%= txtDepoAlani.UniqueID %>': {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    '<%= txtGunlukPaletAdedi.UniqueID %>': {
                        minlength: 2,
                        companynumber: true,
                        required: true
                    },
                    '<%= txtGunlukDepoisisi.UniqueID %>': {
                        minlength: 2,
                        required: true
                    },
                    '<%= txtElektrikIndeksi.UniqueID %>': {
                        required: true,
                        selectcheck: true

                    }
                },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.required').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                },
                success: function (element) {
                    element
                            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                            .closest('.required').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
                }
            });
            jQuery.validator.addMethod('selectcheck', function (value) {
                return (value != '0');
            }, "year required");
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("companynumber", function (value, element) {
                var regexp = /^[0-9 ]+$/;
                return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
            }, "Enter a valid Company Number.");

            jQuery.validator.addMethod(     //adding a method to validate select box//
                    "chosen",
                    function (value, element) {
                        return (value == null ? false : (value.length == 0 ? false : true))
                    },
                    "MainContent_RightContent_dtTarihplease select an option"//custom message
            );
        }

        $(function () {
            $("#MainContent_RightContent_dtTarih").datepicker();

            $("#<%= ddlDepoId.UniqueID %>").onchange(function (){
                alert($(this).val());
            })
        });
    </script>




    <style>
        /*.chosen-container {
            width: 250px !important;
        }

        .chosen-single {
            width: 250px !important;
        }*/
    </style>

    <div class="iletisimdiv" id="divIletisim" runat="server">
        <div id="conform" data-id="conform" class="highlight">
            <div class="contactarea divids">
                <div>
                    <div class="formrows innovaForms" style="margin-top: 50px;">

                        <div class="column leftcolumn required">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepoId" DataTextField="DepoAdi" DataValueField="DepoId" CssClass="chosen-select" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column rightcolumn required">
                            <input type="text" id="dtTarih" runat="server" class="pkinnovaTextArea">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="formrows innovaForms ">
                        <div class="column leftcolumn required">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepoAlani" CssClass="pkinnovaTextArea numeric-input" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column rightcolumn required">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGunlukPaletAdedi" CssClass="pkinnovaTextArea numeric-input" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="formrows innovaForms">
                        <div class="column leftcolumn required">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtGunlukDepoisisi" CssClass="pkinnovaTextArea numeric-input" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column rightcolumn required">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtElektrikIndeksi" CssClass="pkinnovaTextArea numeric-input" runat="server" ValidationGroup="form"></asp:TextBox>
                           <asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="szdfg" ID="HiddenField" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <asp:Button ID="BtnGonder" OnClientClick=' return formcontrol();' CssClass="contactsubmit" runat="server" Text="Kaydet" OnClick="BtnGonder_Click" ValidationGroup="form" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div runat="server" id="message" visible="false"></div>


</asp:Content>
```

Here my C# code

```
public partial class DepoBilgiFormu : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["clicked"] = null;
            BindDepoAdi();
            dtTarih.Attributes.Add("placeholder", GetLocalResourceObject("datetime").ToString());
            txtDepoAlani.Attributes.Add("placeholder", GetLocalResourceObject("storeArea").ToString());
            txtGunlukPaletAdedi.Attributes.Add("placeholder", GetLocalResourceObject("DailyTrackNumber").ToString());
            txtGunlukDepoisisi.Attributes.Add("placeholder", GetLocalResourceObject("DailyStoreHeat").ToString());
            txtElektrikIndeksi.Attributes.Add("placeholder", GetLocalResourceObject("ElectricityMeterIndex").ToString());

        }
    }
    protected void BindDepoAdi()
    {
        using (UlkerEntity entity = new UlkerEntity())
        {
            ddlDepoId.DataSource = entity.tblDepoes.ToList();
            ddlDepoId.Items.Insert(0,
                new ListItem
                {
                    Enabled = true,
                    Text = GetLocalResourceObject("whichideas").ToString(),
                    Value = "0"
                });
            ddlDepoId.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected void BtnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["clicked"] == null)
        {
            UlkerEntity entity = new UlkerEntity();
            tblDepoBilgiFormu bilgi = new tblDepoBilgiFormu();

            bilgi.DepoAlani = Convert.ToInt32(txtDepoAlani.Text);
            bilgi.GunlukPaletAdeti = Convert.ToInt32(txtGunlukPaletAdedi.Text);
            bilgi.GunlukDepoisisi = Convert.ToInt32(txtGunlukDepoisisi.Text);
            bilgi.ElektrikIndeksi = Convert.ToInt32(txtElektrikIndeksi.Text);
            bilgi.LanguageId = ProClass.Culture.CurrentLanguageId;

            DateTime YeniTarih = Convert.ToDateTime( dtTarih.Value.Substring(3, 2) + "." + dtTarih.Value.Substring(0, 2) + "." + dtTarih.Value.Substring(6, 4));

            bilgi.Date = YeniTarih;

            if (ddlDepoId.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                bilgi.DepoId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDepoId.SelectedItem.Value); (PROBLEM İS HERE)
            }

            entity.AddTotblDepoBilgiFormus(bilgi);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            entity.Dispose();


            divIletisim.Visible = false;
            message.Visible = true;
            message.InnerText = "Bilgiler alınmıştır";

            this.txtDepoAlani.Text = "";
            this.txtElektrikIndeksi.Text = "";
            this.txtGunlukDepoisisi.Text = "";
            this.txtGunlukPaletAdedi.Text = "";
            this.ddlDepoId.SelectedIndex = 0;

            Session["clicked"] = true;
        }
    }

}
```

There is a problem at the dropdownlist. I cannot my dropdown to database dropdown's name is empty.
can anyone help me for this problem? Thank u.

Comment: Why is the Value=0 for GetLocalResourceObject("whichideas") ?

Comment: Value =0 meaning ( first rank is in the dropdownlist like this value 0= chosee your select value 1= Store, value 2= store2 etc..

Comment: I think there's a typo. Could you please rephrase this part "I cannot my dropdown to database dropdown's name is empty". It's missing the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear as there's a typo. But I noticed something possibly unintentional in your code: You're inserting an item to dropdownlist then calling Databind which is essentially overwriting the Items collection.

If your problem is not having the item you're inserting then switch the places of the insert and databind calls such as:

```
ddlDepoId.DataSource = entity.tblDepoes.ToList();
ddlDepoId.DataBind();
ddlDepoId.Items.Insert(0,
    new ListItem
    {
        Enabled = true,
        Text = GetLocalResourceObject("whichideas").ToString(),
        Value = "0"
    });
```